# Count number of occurrences in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

I want to select the title column from `[listings]` and the number of occurrences that listing has in the [ads] table, based on the same userid value.

Result should look like:

```
[title] [cnt]  
Acme    5  
MSFT    10  
GOOG    7
```

etc

This doesn't work:

```
select 
    l.title,
    (COUNT (id) FROM ads WHERE ads.userid = l.userid) as cnt
from 
    listings l
INNER JOIN 
    ads a on a.userid = l.userid
WHERE 
    l.listingtype = 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the query and other answers are over complex

```
select 
    l.title,
    COUNT (a.id) as cnt
from 
    listings l
INNER JOIN 
    ads a on a.userid = l.userid
WHERE 
    l.listingtype = 2
GROUP BY l.title
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `group by` clause to achive it.

Something  like this:-

```
select l.title,COUNT (id) 
(SELECT  COUNT (id) FROM ads WHERE ads.userid=l.userid) as cnt
from listings l
INNER JOIN ads a on a.userid=l.userid
WHERE l.listingtype=2
group by l.title
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `SELECT` in your subquery:

```
SELECT
    l.title,
    (SELECT COUNT (id) FROM ads WHERE ads.userid = l.userid) AS cnt
FROM 
    listings l
INNER JOIN 
    ads a on a.userid = l.userid
WHERE 
    l.listingtype = 2
```